# TextBox - Can I keep the selection highlight when it loses focus?

Tags: c#, textbox, focus, selection, highlighting

I would like to have a regular `TextBox` on my form, where the selected text is still highlighted even if you use another control, e.g. push a button.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this (without using a `RichTextBox` which is not suitable for what I am doing).

Answer (score 20):

Sounds like you are looking for the [**HideSelection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection(v=VS.71).aspx) property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected text in the text box control remains highlighted when the control loses focus.

Answer (score 10):

The [`HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection.aspx) property is your friend. Set it to `false` and you should get what you are looking for. I never quite understood why the default is `true`.